# Почему из функции возвращается результат NaN?

Tags: javascript

Задача состоит в суммировании значений свойств объекта, спроверкой "на число". Да, задачу можно решить разными способами и решил я ее через - typeof nums[el] === 'number' ?  acc += nums[el] : acc, но почему именно в нижеукзанном варианте возвращается NaN?

```
const objectWithNumbers = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  c: 'string',
  d: 12,
}

const sumObjectValues = (nums) => {

  return Object.keys(nums).reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (typeof nums[el] === 'number') {
         return acc += nums[el]
        } 
  }, 0)

}

const result = sumObjectValues(objectWithNumbers)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Если проверка на число не будет пройдена, то какой результат вернёт стрелочная функция?

Comment: @andreymal, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: Undefined! Спасибо, теперь все понятно, получается после блока if не хватает "return acc", чтобы код заработал.

Comment: @Qwertiy это не ответ, а наводящий вопрос ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯